# Are there server with rank limit in battlefield 4?

Tags: battlefield-4

I always end up playing with people with ranks 100+. Are there servers that have rank limits?

Comment: not sure about BF4, but in BF3 there were some servers like "Noob only, max level 40" or so. And the server was configured that way, that it would kick all players above that level cap. But DICE didn't include that feature into servers per default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there are no servers that have a rank limit on them. Which is a shame because I think that it would be a good idea, especially for new players.

The main reason you're getting into game with people rank 100+ is that the game is almost a year old, most people have got to rank 100, so many in fact that DICE have upped the level cap 3 times since the game launched, with it now at 130. Level cap was raised with each release of DLC's.

Comment: Thanks for the response, ughhh I was hoping that I just never noticed a cap limit or something :(

Answer (score 1):

I think it's sucks. I've had the game since release and am only at rank 46. No I don't get to play a lot. I have a life, but when I get on I am immediately overwhelmed with people over 100 rank. I can't ever take them out no matter what I do. Maybe two kills a match against rank 100+. Or I constantly am getting killed over and over by one person. Annoying. I don't know how people just spot me out all the time and do that. One in every game almost. Can get killed on far end of map, yet when I spawn again no where near the last death spot here comes the guy that just killed me. When are games going to be fair instead of feeding people that have no life or job that somehow gets everything handed to them?

Comment: Yeah it is a shame that there is no effort to group people based on similar skill. Even after all this time EA still never gave us this feature :(

Your best bet might be to join a clan or recruit some friends to play with you. Also if you do play by yourself, be picky about your squad and stick with your squad-mates. Lone-wolves are pretty vulnerable in BF4 unless you are an expert player.

Comment: Also, there is a distinct possibility of people cheating.  I'm not one to claim "you cheated because you killed me"… but I also hate this uncertainty: am I just really this bad or are they really this good or are they just (low-key so it's harder to detect) hacking?